# extract some data from a huge dataset

Tags: python

I have a huge dataset about airbnb in the world.
This dataset have 5500 city in it.
I want to work only on 'London', 'Paris' and 'Berlin'
So from my original dataset name 'df'
I want to creat a new dataset 'filtered_df' with only all the data from these 3 cities.
I have a variable 'City', so i tried this below but doesn't work as i want.

`df_berlin = df['City']== 'Berlin'`

`df_paris = df['City']== 'Paris'`

`df_london = df['City']== 'London'`

`filtered_df = [df_berlin + df_paris + df_london]`

Comment: It's not surprising that this does not do anyting. It's just assigning `False` to all three o your filter variables and adds them up to result in `[0]`. What format is your dataset in and what framework do you use to work with it? There may be a built-in subset method you can use.

Comment: Maybe you can try something like ```df_paris = df["Paris"]```

Comment: my dataset is in CSV format, and i'm working on jupiter with python.
I get a key error when using df_paris = df["Paris"], because Paris, London and Berlin are in the column 'City'

Comment: I'm just beginning with Pandas, too, so I'm not sure if it's right, but does `df[df.City=='Berlin']` do it?

Comment: No :/ i just get all the column names, but not the data about berlin

Comment: I think we need to know exactly what format the data is in, otherwise it's just guesswork ;/

Comment: @pandawan run `df.head()` and add output in the question. It will gives some insight about your dataset. I assume that you have converted your csv format dataset into a `pandas DataFrame` using `read_csv()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: How about `filtered_df = df.loc[df['City'].isin(['Berlin', 'Paris', 'London'])]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_berlin=df[df.City=='Berlin']
df_paris=df[df.City=='Paris']
df_london=df[df.City=='London']
filtered_df = df_berlin.append(df_paris.append(df_london))
filtered_df.sort_index(inplace=True,kind='mergesort')
```

I tried to simulate this on a small dataset and it worked, for your dataset since it is huge, you can use mergesort and it should work I guess.

Comment: Perfect, your code work perfectly thanks a lot, you just made a small misstake, .append(df_london) and not .append(london)

Comment: Corrected it :)